# How to extract one integer value from multiple integers present

Tags: java, python, regex

I have the following string, output of df command.

```
$ df |grep data
/dev/block/dm-1  11066964 2103848   8946732  20% /data
```

I want to extract value

```
8946732
```

using java regex, I have tried

```
(.*?\s{3}\d+.\d+)
```

but it is not working fine.

Comment: *using java regex* but you have a Python tag

Comment: Split on spaces and keep the fourth element.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I can use python regex as reference

Answer (score 1):

If your expected output is always on fixed index, then you can use this :

```
>>> s = "/dev/block/dm-1  11066964 2103848   8946732  20% /data"
>>> s.split()[3]
'8946732'
```

ok, so as requested with using regex, here it is

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'(?is)(.*?\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+)(\d+)',s).group(2)
'8946732'
```

Comment: I need to use regex only

Comment: here you go, I have edited my answer, but I strongly recommend you to not use regex

Answer (score 1):

using regex as below, it match non space follow by 2 digits then capture next digits

```
import re
re.match('\S+\s+(?:\d+\s+){2}(\d+)', "/dev/block/dm-1  11066964 2103848   8946732  20% /data").group(1)
# '8946372'
```

refer [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ZVU48/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can ask `df` to print a specific column with the `--output` option:

```
df --output=avail /dev/block/dm-1 | tail -n1
```

The `tail` command is just for stripping the header `Avail` out.